# Bars resize (shrink) when I add a new bar to the bar chart, but when removing it, bars stay small

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, flot, bar-chart

I'm using Flot to chart some bar charts on my website.

When I draw a chart with three bars for example, everything renders fine. Then I can add a fourth bar and the bars get thinner and accommodate themselves properly (sort of like what Highcharts does with default settings).

When I remove a bar from that same chart, the bars stay thin and resized and **do not** grow back to their previous state.

Any ideas how I can achieve this effect? Does Flot offer this functionality? Their documentation doesn't mention anything like this and I'm afraid I may be overlooking something.

Comment: How are you adding the bars?  Are you calling $.plot again, or using setData/setupGrid/draw?  What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: Some example code would be helpful.